# fetching image from firebase to flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

if statement is gets false and else statement is running

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const Text('no data');
            }
```

[image: Firebase]

[image: StreamBuilder]

Comment: Welcome to SO. If the `If` statement evaluates to false then either `snapshot.hasData` evaluates false and/or `snapshot.date != NULL` evaluates to false. There's not much more we can tell you without more info in the question. Did you do some troubleshooting to see why those were false? Please include code, errors and structures as *text*, not links and images. Links can break and are not searchable which may prevent readers from locating the question. Please see [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)